# Objective Normalized Measure

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I have a question about readNormalizedMeasure attribute in manifest. Please see the following SCORM 2004 3rd edition manifest. Where does the Activity 3 read its normalized measure from? Please explain for me. Thank you very much.

```
<organization identifier = "OB-03c">
    <title>Content Package 1</title>
    <item identifier = "activity_1" identifierref = "SEQ01">
        <title>Activity 1</title>
        <imsss:sequencing>
            <imsss:sequencingRules>
                <imsss:preConditionRule>
                    <imsss:ruleConditions>
                        <imsss:ruleCondition operator="not" condition="objectiveStatusKnown"/>
                    </imsss:ruleConditions>
                    <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
                </imsss:preConditionRule>
            </imsss:sequencingRules>
            <imsss:objectives>
                <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ">
                    <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj-OB03-3" />
                </imsss:primaryObjective>
            </imsss:objectives>
        </imsss:sequencing>
    </item>
    <item identifier = "activity_2">
        <title>Activity 2</title>
        <item identifier = "activity_3">
            <title>Activity 3</title>
            <item identifier = "activity_4" identifierref = "SEQ01">
                <title>Activity 4</title>
            </item>
            <item identifier = "activity_5" identifierref = "SEQ01">
                <title>Activity 5</title>
                <imsss:sequencing>
                    <imsss:sequencingRules>
                        <imsss:preConditionRule>
                            <imsss:ruleConditions>
                                <imsss:ruleCondition condition = "satisfied"/>
                            </imsss:ruleConditions>
                            <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
                        </imsss:preConditionRule>
                    </imsss:sequencingRules>
                    <imsss:objectives>
                        <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ">
                            <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj-OB03-1" />
                        </imsss:primaryObjective>
                    </imsss:objectives>
                </imsss:sequencing>
            </item>
            <item identifier = "activity_6" identifierref = "SEQ01">
                <title>Activity 6</title>
            </item>
            <imsss:sequencing>
                <imsss:controlMode choice = "false" flow = "true"/>
                <imsss:sequencingRules>
                    <imsss:preConditionRule>
                        <imsss:ruleConditions>
                            <imsss:ruleCondition condition = "satisfied"/>
                        </imsss:ruleConditions>
                        <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
                    </imsss:preConditionRule>
                </imsss:sequencingRules>
                <imsss:objectives>
                    <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ" satisfiedByMeasure = "true">
                        <imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>0.6</imsss:minNormalizedMeasure>
                        <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj-OB03-3" readSatisfiedStatus = "false" writeSatisfiedStatus = "true" />
                    </imsss:primaryObjective>
                </imsss:objectives>
            </imsss:sequencing>
        </item>
        <item identifier = "activity_7" identifierref = "SEQ01">
            <title>Activity 7</title>
            <imsss:sequencing>
                <imsss:sequencingRules>
                    <imsss:preConditionRule>
                        <imsss:ruleConditions>
                            <imsss:ruleCondition operator = "not" condition = "satisfied"/>
                        </imsss:ruleConditions>
                        <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
                    </imsss:preConditionRule>
                </imsss:sequencingRules>
                <imsss:objectives>
                    <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ">
                        <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj-OB03-2" />
                    </imsss:primaryObjective>
                </imsss:objectives>
            </imsss:sequencing>
        </item>
        <item identifier = "activity_8" identifierref = "SEQ01">
            <title>Activity 8</title>
            <imsss:sequencing>
                <imsss:sequencingRules>
                    <imsss:preConditionRule>
                        <imsss:ruleConditions>
                            <imsss:ruleCndition operator = "not" condition = "satisfied"/>
                            <imsss:ruleCondition operator = "not" condition = "objectiveStatusKnown" referencedObjective = "obj1"/>
                        </imsss:ruleConditions>
                        <imsss:ruleAction action = "skip"/>
                    </imsss:preConditionRule>
                </imsss:sequencingRules>
                <imsss:objectives>
                    <imsss:primaryObjective objectiveID = "PRIMARYOBJ">
                        <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID="gObj-OB03-2" />
                    </imsss:primaryObjective>
                    <imsss:objective objectiveID = "obj1" >
                        <imsss:mapInfo targetObjectiveID = "gObj-OB03-3" />
                    </imsss:objective>
                </imsss:objectives>
            </imsss:sequencing>
        </item>
        <imsss:sequencing>
            <imsss:controlMode choice = "false" flow = "true"/>
        </imsss:sequencing>
    </item>
    <item identifier = "activity_9" identifierref = "SEQ01">
        <title>Activity 9</title>
    </item>
    <imsss:sequencing>
        <imsss:controlMode choice = "false" flow = "true"/>
    </imsss:sequencing>
</organization>
```

Answer (score 1):

Activity 3 does not read any tracking data at all. The only activities which read tracking data are Activity 1 and Activity 8 and they read objectiveSatisfiedStatus from the primary objective of Activity 3. To test your manifest and learn more, download LMS2004 from http://www.naseelco.com. It has a Test Mode where you can learn a lot about your SCORM manifest. Here is a snapshot of your manifest loaded into LMS2004 where you can see which activities read/write tracking data.

[image: LMS2004]

Comment: Please download a trial version of LMS2004. Open your manifest file then select the activity you want to check its data. On the menu bar, click on Test Mode. Then select "Objectives".

Comment: Could you give me more explanation about sections "Written By" and "Read By" in the above screenshot, please?

Comment: "Written By" refers to the objective which has written its tracking data to the Global Objective in the mapInfo section of the manifest. "Read By" refers to the objectives which can read the tracking data of the Golobal Objective.

Comment: When does readSatisfiedStatus occurs?
When does writeSatisfiedStatus occurs?

What information are read when readSatisfiedStatus is set to True?
What information are written when writeSatisfiedStatus is set to True?

Comment: When does readSatisfiedStatus occurs? When does writeSatisfiedStatus occurs? They occur immediately after terminating a SCO and before the rollup process starts. What information are read when readSatisfiedStatus is set to True? It reads Satisfied Status and Objective progress status. What information are written when writeSatisfiedStatus is set to True? It reads Normalized Measure and Objective Measure Status.

Comment: You said "They occur immediately after terminating a SCO and before the rollup process starts". Which process are you referring exactly? Thank you very much for your help @FadelMS